# Installng FastCGI++

Tags: boost, installation, fastcgi++

I am installing `fastcgi++` from http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/

It required the boost libraries and I configure using the following

```
sudo ./configure --with-boost=/home/test/boost
```

But I get the below error. How do I fix? Its finding my boost. Hmmmm

```
checking for Boost's header version... 1_48
checking boost/bind.hpp usability... yes
checking boost/bind.hpp presence... yes
checking for boost/bind.hpp... yes
checking for the toolset name used by Boost for g++... gcc45 -gcc
checking boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp usability... yes
checking boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp presence... yes
checking for boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp... yes
checking for the Boost date_time library... no
configure: error: cannot find the flags to link with Boost date_time
```

Comment: Did you actually build Boost or merely extract its sources?

Answer (score 3):

run

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-date-time1.40-dev
```

probably you'll also need other like libboost-system, find then with

```
apt-cache search libboost
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran the following command, but I got the same error

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev libboost-date-time-dev
```

There were a lot of packages missing in my boost installation. My `configure` error was solved when I executed

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

which installed all boost libraries. Be aware that it will install the most recent boost libraries in your repositories. In my case, it installed `1.46` version, while the current version in the [boost website](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_51_0.html) is `1.51`.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the fastcgi++ configure script when using boost libraries > 1.49. Here's the [bug ticket](http://savannah.nongnu.org/support/?108268).

This has been fixed, so [download fastcgi++ 2.1 or later](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/fastcgipp/). An alternative workaround is to use older versions of boost (as mentioned in the other answers).

Answer (score 0):

What a pain,
My boost binary that came with my distribution repository does not included following dependencies too.

```
#libboost-syste-dev
#libboost-date-time-dev
#libboost-iostreams-dev
```

If you having the same trouble , I think it's better to download whole the boost source and compile it manually, rather than installing a missing dependency and running again ./configure to find out what would miss next.

NOTE: as mentioned in an earlier

```
 #apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

would make it work. But I didn't tested it yet.